# Comparing rows of two column in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please help!!

I have a Data Frame which is merge of two Data Frame

I want to compare status column with status_new column where status != status_new and status is not blank then Status = Status_new.

Dataframe:

```
         id  status   emailaddress ownername Action status_new  emailaddress_new ownername_new      
         a   pending  a.gmail.com   as             submitted    a.gmail.com       as
         b   pending  b.gmail.com   bs             submitted    b.gmail.com       bs
         c   submitted c.gmail.com  cs             submitted    dc.gmail.com      cs
         d   submitted d.gmail.com   ds            submitted    d.gmail.com       ds
```

code

```
    for index, row in df_result.iterrows():
        
        if ( row['Status_new'] != row['Status']):
            row["Status"] = row['Status_new']
            print(row["Status"])
            row["Action"] = "update"
```

But its not updating the rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Looking at your code, do you also want the Status column updated for rows that change value?

Comment: yes,I only want to change where there is a mismatch.

Comment: How does it make a difference? The result is identical

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped. I meant, would you also like the 'Action' column to display 'update' where each row has a new updated status? It wasn't specified in the asked question, but seems to be desired in the code block

Comment: Yes I want to update the Action column as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to find rows were your status is not the same as your new status OR rows where the status is blank. You can do that using logic:

```py
rows_to_modify = (df_result['status'] != df_result['new_status']) | df_result['status'].isnull()
```

Using this, you can update the rows you need:

```py
# Update status column
df_result['status'][rows_to_modify] = df_result['new_status'][rows_to_modify]

# update action column to 'update'
df_result['Action'][rows_to_modify] = 'update'
```

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to check for status and status_new equality. If they are equal, it doesn't matter to replace the value.

This simplifies the problem to a simple `where`. You can use:

```
df_results['Action'] = df_results['Action'].where(df_results['status'].eq('null')|df_results['status'].eq(df_results['status_new']), 'updated')

df_results['status'] = df_results['status'].where(df_results['status'].eq('null'), df_results['status_new'])
```

Comment: blank means if the status is null

Comment: Like the string 'null' or like NaN?

Comment: like string null.Also Can you explain why my code is not working

Comment: Not the direct reason why it is not working, but you should try not to use `iterrows`, it is inefficient

Comment: When you iterate through rows, you aren't able to change the values within the DataFrame directly. @mozway is also correct, iterating through the df using `iterrows` will cause performance to suffer.

Instead, you should modify values using indexing and logic

Comment: Did you get a warning?

Comment: It works in one place but does not in other. So I am confused. Also I want to capture the action column if the update happens then update the Action column with "update" text.

Comment: You have to be more specific, edit your question to provide a non working example. I updated the answer to add the "Action" logic.